# New to Unix, want to create a simple user input to restart or leave the program

Tags: user-input

I am making a program and want a simple echo asking if the user wants to Order again, or Leave the program. It's in Shell on Unix

The program is simple echo and reading of variables of ordering food. What food do you want, how much KG, etc, and it summarises it all up at the end.

Now I want the program to ask if the user wants to 'Order again?', but I have no idea how to add an if statement for Yes or No when inputted to restart the program, or exit it if they say no.

Any help appreciated. Sounds very simple, but I found no help online anywhere.

Comment: What language are you writing this program in?

Comment: @Jesse_b It's on Unix in Shell Script

Comment: Which Unix? Which shell scripting language variant?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

read -rp 'Fish or chicken? ' protein
read -rp 'Beans or rice? ' starch
read -rp 'Broccoli or asparagus? ' veggie
read -rp 'Beer or beer? ' drink

echo "You have ordered the $protein with a side of $starch and $veggie, and to drink you will have $drink"

while true; do
    read -rp 'Would you like to order again? ' order
    if echo "order" | grep -iq 'yes'; then
        exec $0
    elif echo "order" | grep -iq 'no'; then
        exit 0
    fi
done
```

`read` is a shell builtin that will read from standard input.  With the `-p` switch it will "prompt" the user and set either the default `REPLY` variable or a specified variable (protein, starch, veggie, drink, etc)

`$0` is a shell special parameter that will expand to the name of the shell within a script the name of the script

If the users response to "Would you like to order again?" is `yes` then the script will be executed again, else it will exit.

---

### References

[read](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/read.html)

[special parameters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02)

[if conditionals](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_07)

[while loop](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_09)

Comment: Thank you, now just a question. What is the difference between read and echo? Is it just a faster way instead of making a variable separately? And I did try something similar, but what does 'fi' do?

Comment: `fi` closes the `if` conditional construct.

Comment: I understand, and I use this code to help me write more. One question I also have is, how do I make this case sensitive to allow caps and non caps, and also, I want the word 'no' to exit specifically.

Comment: case sensitive or case insensitive?

Comment: insensitive, sorry.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a loop that will keep asking until a yes or no answer is received.  `grep` with the -i option will be case insensitive

Comment: I tried but it says redirection unexpected

Comment: Pretty sure <<< is a feature bash added, that is not supported by /bin/sh. I’d suggest `case`